# htaccess url rewriting and and https

Tags: .htaccess, https, url-rewriting

I have a website that was previously set for an http address on a server.
Now I changed the server and the website is supposed to be https.

So I decided to make changes in the .htaccess file but it doesn't work (500 error, the webpage doesn't appear)

Here is my htaccess file content :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    
#allow to add "www." if missing
    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R,NE]

php_flag "allow_url_fopen" "On"

# URL rewrites

   RewriteRule ^home$  /index.php?content=home&lang=en [L]
   RewriteRule ^home-notice-1$  /index.php?content=home&val=1&lang=en [L]
   RewriteRule ^home-notice-2$  /index.php?content=home&val=2&lang=en [L]
   RewriteRule ^home-notice-3$  /index.php?content=home&val=3&lang=en [L]
   RewriteRule ^featured-news$  /index.php?content=news&mode=featured&lang=en [L]            
   etc...
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong ?
Basically, all I changed compared to before is that I added "RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off" and changed "RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http:..." to "RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https:...".
And, of course "mywebsite.com" is a placeholder for the real name of my website, which I obviously typed correctly.

Here is what seems to be the structure from the ftp client point of view :

from root to index.php:

```
->rb4t7.ftp.mywebhost.com
    ->sites (folder)
        ->mywebsite.com (folder)
             .htaccess (file)
             index.php (file)
             ...
```

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have access to that. (I think). it's a commercial distant proprietary server and I don't seem to have access to anything but ftp and phpmyadmin

Comment: Within the ftp client I can have access to various folders in my server but none of them contains any file that logs the errors (I opened them all). There is one folder called "ik-logs" and it's empty, even after refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, all I had to do is just copy/paste the part below "#URL Rewrites". Everything else was messing up with the system apparently. The https was natively taken care of somehow.
Thanks